# After trying to run this simple code I can only type in value once, why?

Tags: c++

After trying to run this simple code I can only type in value once, why?
(compiler is g++)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* str = new char[10];
    cin.get(str, sizeof(str));

    char* strline = new char[10];
    cin.getline(strline, sizeof(strline));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin.get(str, sizeof(str));` reads the first 7==8-1 (1 byte for zero terminator) characters of your input (or until first delimiter) because `sizeof(str)` returns the size of pointer and it's 8 in your case. It doesn't clear the stream and doesn't remove the default delimiter `\n`. `cin.getline` reads up to 7 characters until newline. E.g. you type `Hello Wor` and press enter. `cin.get` reads `Hello W` and `cin.getline` reads `or`.

Comment: In my case cin.get reads "Hello W" and cin.getline reads "or". Is there any way I can get my code working as intended?

Comment: @anxiety_rgb What Is the intended way? Why do you use `cin.get` and `cin.getline`? You should prefer `std::string`